# Property 'transitions' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, makestyles

Could you please help me with Material ui with React? Below is my issue

If I do `import makeStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles'`, On loading the application it throws a warning saying...

```
makeStyles needs to be imported from '@material-ui/styles'
```

But when I do `import makeStyles from '@material-ui/styles'`, it says that...

```
theme is undefined
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Could you show me a little bit of code?

Comment: Also, can you mention what version of `material-ui` that you're using?